# Pygame windows not responding

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to coding, in a try to make a small game, my pygame window is not responding, can anyone verify my code and tell me were is the problem, please?

Python version: Python 3.8
Pygame version: pygame 1.9.6

Is problem in the versions, have conflicts or something?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*


pygame.init()
width, height= 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos=[100,100]


player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load ("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load ("resources/images/castle.png")


while 1:


    screen.fill(0)

    for x in range(width//grass.get_width()+1):

        for y in range(height//grass.get_height()+1):
            screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))
            screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
            screen.blit(castle,(0,135))
            screen.blit(castle,(0,240))
            screen.blit(castle,(0,345 ))
    screen.blit(player, playerpos)

    pygame.display.flip()


for event in pygame.event.get():


    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:

        pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_w:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key==K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key==K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key==K_d:
                keys[3]=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=False

if keys[0]:
    playerpos[1]-=5
elif keys[2]:
    playerpos[1]+=5
if keys[1]:
    playerpos[0]-=5
elif keys[3]:
    playerpos[0]+=5
exit(0)
```

Comment: Any error logs on terminal?

Comment: It look like the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop isn't nested ***inside*** the outer `while 1:` loop.